# Do I need to specify Rcpp in both Imports and LinkingTo in order to avoid a Makevars file?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

According to the [Rcpp FAQ](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) (2.15. What about the new ‘no-linking’ feature), since Rcpp version 0.11.0 we can avoid specifying LAPACK/BLAS/Fortran in a Makevars file, and in fact avoid a Makevars entirely if we follow these instructions.

`... only two things are required:
• an entry in DESCRIPTION such as Imports: Rcpp (which
may be versioned as in Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.11.0)), and
• an entry in NAMESPACE to ensure Rcpp is correctly instantiated,
for example importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp).`

But instead of adding an `Imports` line for Rcpp, would a `LinkingTo` also work?  That is, can I use:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp (>= 0.11.0)
```

instead of:

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.11.0)
```

Or are both needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no -- you need both just as we say as they have different purposes.

`LinkingTo:` is, for all intents and purposes, a directive for R to tell the compiler where needed header files are.  Packages building against Rcpp *must* have this.

`Imports:` deals with the package namespace and initialization on package load / attach. Rcpp is "almost" purely header-based but a little bit of code needs to be executed.

All this is documented for R in the *Writing R Extensions* manual and for Rcpp in our package vignettes.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed Hadley's `devtools::use_rcpp()` adds Rcpp to both `Imports` and `LinkingTo`, but doesn't add the `importFrom` line to the Namespace file, so a user should still do that manually?

Comment: You could just look at our documentation instead of asking me about usage patterns with a 3rd party tool I do not use myself...

Comment: Just use `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and see what it does. That works.  The RStudio package generator for Rcpp is also good.

Comment: Thank you again.  Indeed, the RStudio package generator does add `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` to the NAMESPACE as specified by your documentation.  Agreed it was unfair to ask about `devtools:use_rcpp()`. Thanks again.

Comment: Not unfair in the sense that `devtools` is very popular. But I have been using R for so long that my workflows never needed it so `<shrug>` from here -- I just cannot answer usage question.  All you asked _is_ both documented _and_ done right by these generators and helper -- just not by the one you picked. Unlucky you.